# Python Script to change keyboard letters

Tags: python, keyboard

I want to know if it's possible to write a script for my keyboard, which can change single letters. For example, I want to type "e" instead of "p". Is it possible to get the "p" after entering a keystroke like "e"?

The purpose is: I've a broken keyboard and I want to replace some letters for my main usage. So the script must run immadiately after entering a keystroke. If that makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend Autohotkey instead.